# Workaround for receiving system broadcasts with app installed to SD card?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, app2sd

It seems as if applications installed to the SD card do not receive any system broadcasts whatsoever. However, we'd like to start a service at boot time that listens for push notifications.

We'd hate to abandon app2sd, since it's a feature that was asked for by many users, so is there any way to have both?

Comment: The problem is that the SD card isn't yet mounted when ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is sent.

Comment: @Chris Stratton,  you should've posted this as an answer. Because it is :)

Comment: You could always let the user choose where to install it, and let them know what features will be disabled if they move it to the sd card.

Comment: Have you looked into replacing your push notification mechanism with http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ ?

Comment: @Chris: thanks! What I don't understand though: I thought I was clever when I tried to catch the EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_READY broadcast to re-launch the push service, but the broadcast was never even received whenever the app was on the SD card. However, EXTERNAL_APPS_READY implies SD card ready, so what's the problem? As to your second question, we use Urban Airship since they support iOS, Blackberry, and Android using a single API. Under the hoods it's actually C2DM on Android though.

Comment: I was under the impression that C2DM did not require re-registration upon reboot.

Comment: No, but the native UA lib does. It registers a boot completed handler to launch itself. We may switch to UA's Helium protocol at some point, which allows as to target devices all the way down to Android 1.6 using the same push API.

Comment: I've read about this before -- http://b.android.com/8485 says that apps on the SD card do not receive the `EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE` broadcast. Which makes no sense.

Comment: One workaround is to listen for `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` broadcasts and use that as a trigger start your service when the network comes up.

Comment: Well, that worked beautifully. I now check in the receiver whether the app is installed on the SD card, and if it is, and connection status is CONNECTED, I start the service. You should re-post that comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Android bug 8485](http://b.android.com/8485), applications on the SD card do not receive the [`EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE) broadcast.  That doesn't make sense to me, so hopefully that gets fixed.

Meanwhile, a workaround would be to listen for [`CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) broadcasts from the system and use that as a trigger start your service once the network becomes available.

Comment: Note that this can happen even if the device just lost network and came back. not just for reboots.

Comment: @ekatz: Yes, as the name implies. But that's pretty much the desired behaviour in this case - you need to reconnect to the push server after losing connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

External SD card will be mounted after BOOT_COMPLETE and other system intents broadcasted.